# can memory leaks occur in pascal pl?

Tags: memory, pascal

I started programming with pascal recently, and I understood that in pascal when exiting the program all memories allocated ( using either new or getmem ) are freed. So can a program written in pascal cause a memory leak despite of that?

I'm asking this because most languages I know can cause memory leaks and I need to know if that is also the case for pascal.

Comment: I think you need to define what you mean by memory leaks or provide a language as an example as one that causes the leaks you mention.  At least in my experience most languages that allow memory leaks are like C and C++ in that the leak is just about always terminated and reclaimed upon process exit.  That is the leak of memory is limited to the process run time.

Comment: Sometimes memory can leak from the computer down onto the floor beneath, so you should check for that.

Comment: for example in C, if you allocate a memory and don't free it before you exit then you will have a memory leak.

Comment: Once a program is exited, the OS releases all of it's memory, handles, etc.. So no, a Pascal (or any other kind of program) can not leak a memory-related resource after it closes. (Notice I said *memory-related resource* - this does *not* include other resources such as temporary files.)

Comment: @user3776836, [`not on Windows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686722%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) whatever language you use.

Answer (score 0):

Upon closing a program in Pascal (or any other language for that matter) on Windows, Windows re-allocates the memory previously taken up by Pascal for other uses.

So no Pascal cannot cause memory leaks but if you're referring to security, memory leaks are not the whole story, there are lots of other things (temporary files, etc.) 'leaked' too.

Answer (score 0):

*memory leak* is a term used to describe a situation that happens when a program is running, not after it ends. You "leak" memory when you allocate it dynamically, but don't deallocate it when you no longer need it. If that situation happens enough times (it would be especially bad in long running programs like servers or inside of a large loop), a memory leak will lead to the program crashing or becoming non-functional because it has used up all the memory the OS has can allocate to it. A program that is consuming excessive memory can also cause the computer system to slow down as the operating system is forced to use virtual memory (on the hard disk) in order to manage all running programs. "memory waste" might be a better term for what occurs.

Whether a program has misused it's memory or not, when it ends, all of that memory returns to the control of the operating system and is available for use by other programs that might start up.